# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in AJAX call Laravel 5.4

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I am trying to use AJAX in forgot password form. Before that I just tried to see a message in console but I'm getting Maximum cal stack size exceeded Error. I searched so many solutions and I came to know it is due to iterative call to a function without limiting condition but couldn't relate to my code.

[image]

**HTML of form:**

```
<form class="form-vertical" id="recoverform" role="form" method="POST">
                <input type="hidden" id="token" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_field() }}">

                    <div class="controls">
                        <div class="main_input_box">
                            <span class="add-on bg_lo"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></span><input id="recover_email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail address" value="{{ old('email') }}" required />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                <div class="form-actions">
                    <span class="pull-left"><a href="#" class="flip-link btn btn-success" id="to-login">&laquo; Back to login</a></span>

                    <span class="pull-right"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Recover
                    </button></span>
                </div>
            </form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
            jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
                $( '#recoverform' ).on( 'submit', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    //var email = $('#recover_email').val();
                    //var host = "{{URL::to('/')}}";
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "{{URL::to('/ajax')}}",
                        data: { '_token': token },
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (response) {
                        console.log('done');
                        }
                    });

                });
            });
        </script>
```

**Route:**

```
Route::POST('ajax', array('uses' => 'HomeController@ajaxTest'))->name('ajax');
```

**Method in HomeController:**

```
public function ajaxTest(){
        $response = array(
            'status' => 'success',
            'msg' => 'Setting created successfully',
        );
        return Response::json($response);  // <<<<<<<<< see this line
    }
```

Comment: have you try to send response with status code like this 

return response()->json(['data'=>$response], 200);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also stuck in this similar problem but I later figure it out. This problem may cause due to recursive function. In my case there wasn't any recursive function. I just fixed my csrf_token and if your problem still remain intact then in Chrome go to network tab in the inspector tools and switch to preview to see the php error message.﻿

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not define the "token" parameter which is used in the below line:

data: { '_token': token }

fix that & try again.